# Unknown type name "SDL_RendererFlip" using SDL2 (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl-2, emscripten

I've tried to compile this SDL2 tutorial using emscripten: [Text input tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/32_text_input_and_clipboard_handling/index.php)

But I've got this error:

```
error: unknown type name 'SDL_RendererFlip'; did you mean 'SDL_RendererFlags'?
error: use of undeclared identifier 'SDL_RenderCopyEx'
```

The `<SDL/SDL.h>` is included. I have no idea why the compiler cannot find the enum, and the function.

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RendererFlip
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx

---

The command line arguments are:

```
emcc main.cpp -o main.html --preload-file files@/ -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=['bmp'] -s USE_SDL_TTF=2
```

The includes at the beginning of the code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <SDL/SDL.h>` includes emscripten built-in SDL 1.3.

`#include <SDL.h>` will use emscripten-ports SDL2.